# CustomView with XIB - indefinite looping in init coder method

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

In my project I am trying to create a custom UIView from a XIB file. I followed few tutorials and arrived at below code to load

```
import UIKit

class StorePricing: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {

        let view = self.loadViewFromXib()

        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    private func loadViewFromXib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return view

    }

}
```

When I add this custom view in another view my app crashed and I noticed the init call is called in a indefinite loop. The call hierarchy is as follows in my custom view

1. Call to init coder
2. Call to setupView()
3. Call to loadViewFromXib()

nib.instantiate calls init coder and the loop becomes indefinite

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your xib file contains an instance of your view, then then it's loaded, it will call init(coder:), which will then load the xib file again, and the cycle will restart. I would either remove instances of your view from the xib file, or don't call setupView() from within init(coder:)

Answer (score 4):

Set the **File’s Owner** Class to your **custom class**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your `setupView()` (executed in `init(coder:)`) loads the nib again which fires `init with coder` again causing infinite recursion.

Do not instantiate the nib inside of the `init(coder:)`. If you want to configure the view after loading it do it for example in `awakeFromNib` method.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting the infinite recursion if, in your .xib file, for your new view (StorePricing) your Custom Class class type is set to your new custom class name (StorePricing). It should be set to UIView.  To understand what' going on, when nib.instantiate(...) is reading the .xib and comes across the Custom Class name for your view, it calls `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to create it, and then, around it goes.
Set the File’s Owner Custom Class to your custom class. This will allow you to establish Referencing Outlets from the .xib file into your code file.

Answer (score 1):

This is because every time you when you call `setupView()` you add sub view. so it happens again every time. for that what i had done you can see below. Hope will help you.

```
class TableBackGroundView: UIView {

  // Here is my common view handled
  var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        xibSetup()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableBackGroundView", bundle: nil)
        view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```